# copy db operation with mongo java driver when auth is enabled

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to do a `copydb` operation using mongo java driver. This is my code to do that

```
String nonce = mongo.getDB("admin").command(new BasicDBObject("copydbgetnonce","1")).get("nonce").toString();
String username = "admin";
String password = "password";
String key = md5(nonce + username + md5(username + ":mongo:" + password));

DBObject copyOp = new BasicDBObject("copydb", "1").
  append("fromdb" , "db1").
  append("todb" , "db2").
  append("username" , username).
  append("nonce" , nonce).
  append("key" , key);

mongo.getDB("admin").command(copyOp);
```

It was working when authentication is disabled on the server. With the authentication it fails with unauthorized result.

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "unauthorized"}
```

I can assure that password and username is correct. Please point me to the correct direction .

PS my mongod instance is `tokumx 1.5`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
final DBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject( );
cmd.put( "copydb", "1" );
cmd.put( "slaveOk", true );
cmd.put( "fromdb", "db1" );
cmd.put( "todb", "db2" );
cmd.put( "fromhost", "fromHost" );

BasicDBObject nonceCmd = new BasicDBObject( );
nonceCmd.put( "copydbgetnonce", 1 );
nonceCmd.put( "fromhost", "fromHost" );
final CommandResult nonceResult = mongo.getDB( "admin" ).command( nonceCmd );
final String nonce = nonceResult.getString( "nonce" );
final byte[ ] innerHex =( getUserName( ) + ":mongo:" + String.valueOf( getPassword( ) ) ).getBytes( );
final byte[ ] outerHex = ( nonce + getUserName( ) + Util.hexMD5( innerHex ) ).getBytes( );

cmd.put( "username", getUserName( ) );
cmd.put( "nonce", nonce );
cmd.put( "key", Util.hexMD5( outerHex ) );

final CommandResult res = mongo.getDB( "admin" ).command( cmd );
if ( !res.ok( ) )
{
    throw res.getException( ) ;
}
```

Comment: Are you answering or confirming?

Comment: Should be sort-of answer